# Selenium не может найти кнопку

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**HTML** копки
 `<button type="button" class="Buttonstyles__BaseButton-hz08m4-0 cjyoqz"><span class="Buttonstyles__ChildrenWrapper-hz08m4-3 bYSkKb"><div class="TextCallout1__TextCallout1Wrapper-qzrnab-0 hFWzEC"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Текст кнопки</font></font></div></span></button>`

Что только не пробовал `driver.execute_script`, `find_element_by_class_name`, `find_element_by_xpath`, `find_element_by_css_selector`.

`WebDriverWait` не помогло.
Мне удалось вызвать `document.querySelector("#skip-tabbar > div:nth-child(2) > article > div:nth-child(3) > div.layout__CardWrapper-sc-775v9d-0.ktgUkv > div.layout__Right-sc-775v9d-2.kowpQa > div.ShowPhoneNumberButton__StyledButton-sc-1fetcgp-0.fXHQwR > button").click()` но в selenium `selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'click' of null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text() = 'Текст кнопки']").click()`

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет именно об этой кнопке

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//font/font[1]").click()
```